# 1980's-90's PBS Sci-fi mini series about light and kids looking for a laser-firing ruby

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Ok, this movie I watched as part of my science class. It is a 1980's-90's PBS Sci-fi mini series about light.

I think there was at least 6 episodes. It was a live action, and the show was about 4 kids.

If I remember right it was staged in a barren desert like place or planet.

The thing I remember most though is how they had to find this giant ruby pendant about the size of a person's palm to either make a laser, or fire a laser, at the bad guy destroying him.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_PBS#Former_programming

Comment: *Tomes and Talismans*?

Comment: If it is *Tomes and Talismans*, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure that is it based on some of the comments made about later episodes. Unfortunately I can't actually check to be sure since the episodes got taken down. Thank you. This was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about [Tomes and Talismans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomes_%26_Talismans), and I think it's episode 4. There is a description [at this website](https://www.trenchcoatsoft.com/tag/tomes-n-talismans/), and the events seem to correlate to the episode about skimming the card catalog to find information.

There is one episode available on youtube, uploaded by Mississippi Public Broadcasting, Episode 1:

The series was originally done by Mississippi ETV (Educational TeleVision) as an explanation of a library and the various parts of a library that existed at that time, and how to use them.